# django form validation

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

In my form I have a following regex field :

```
code = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\d{2}[-]\d{3}', max_length=6, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict), label="Postal code")
```

how to create clean method for this field checking if the regex requirements are met ? I'd like to have a custom message here, not django's built in (if it gives any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems similar to this: [Django override default form error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481771/django-override-default-form-error-messages)