# django list of all possible error messages which a CharField form validator can raise?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-errors

I created a model like this

```
class Users(models.Model):
    alpha_field = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', message='Name can only contain letters')
    username = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='first Name', validators=[alpha_field])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[alpha_field])
    password = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

and I made a form out of it and I want to raise my own error messages.

class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Users
    widgets = {'password':forms.PasswordInput()}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super( UsersForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields[ 'username' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Username"
    self.fields[ 'first_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="First Name"  
    self.fields[ 'last_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Last Name"
    self.fields[ 'password' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Password"
    self.fields['first_name'].label='first Name'
    self.fields['first_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'First Name is Required'}
```

as you can see, I already created the error message if the first_name field was not filled out. However, I know that the CharField can raise a lot more error messages (for example, if submitted first_name is greater than the max_length). I want to have a custom error message for each and every possible error message which can be raised. Is there a place where I can see a list of all the possible error messages which a CharField form can raise?

Also, my verbose name in first_name is not working, if I can get the verbose name to work than I wouldn't need to create a custom message for the error messages. Note that I did already create a thread about the verbose_name not working and I still haven't figured out the exact reason as to why it isn't working. If the verbose_name can start working, that would be great. Here is a link to the thread:

[django verbose_name not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015990/django-verbose-name-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation on all the default error message keys for each field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-field-classes Maybe try googling next time?

Comment: Ohhh, so those are the ONLY error messages which can be raised for CharField? Just required, max_length and min_length? Django doesn't check for anything else?