# How do I get rid of the password constraints (eg. password has to be 8 characters, password can't be too similar to username, etc.) in django

Tags: python, django

I need to get rid of the password constraints in the default django password register system so that a user doesn't need to have the password be eight characters or the password can't be too similar to the username, and be able to add my own password constraints such as a strength detector.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting [AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation) is a list of validators/constraints that a user's password must pass. If you use `startproject` these will be set to include both constraints you mention. You can remove them from the setting

For example, this is what the setting looks like from a fresh project started using `startproject` using the latest version of Django

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    { # This validates against the username
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    { # This validates the length
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was also wondering while creating a registration form, how do I specify what field needs to be filled out when giving an error in django. Right now the error is just "this field is required," but how do I change this field into the actual field like password, or username or something.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be specified like password is required or username is required, instead of this field is required

Comment: That's a little more complex, you would have to override the registration form and add these messages there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481771/django-override-default-form-error-messages