# Django model string representation

Tags: python, django

I know that a model object string representation can be achieved by adding

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But this is the representation of an *object* of Company but not the model class itself. Meaning if I create an object

```
obj = Company(name='string_repr', email='example@example.com')
```

`print(obj)` would result in `'string_repr'` which is as expected since Im getting the string representation of the object, not the class/ model. However I noticed that during a `CreateView` form validation in case if there already is an object of the model with the same email Django returns an error message that there already is a *Company* with such an email (picture is not in English but the underlined section is the only relevant part).

[image]

I suppose the error message is taking the class name and inputting it in the message, but is there a way how to alter the string representation of the model (class) name? Its needed for translation purposes. I guess I could just rename the class names to local language but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1488660/152016

Comment: @Niloct I suppose it does regarding the error message content, although I'm still curious about the string representation of the model itself